# how to remove a form field in embedded forms from symfony 2 controller

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.3

I have a form as below:

```
class AdminEmployerForm extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
            ->add('firstName', 'text')
            ->add('user', new AdminUserForm());
    }
}


class AdminUserForm extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
            ->add('username', 'text')
            ->add('email', 'text');
    }
}
```

I am calling AdminEmployerForm in controller and I want to remove email field of AdminUserForm from AdminEmployerForm:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new AdminEmployerForm, $employer);
//i want to do something like $form->remove('email')
```

how can i do use $form->remove() to remove field in embedded form? Is it possible to remove a field of embedded form from controller?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You'll have to *get* the embedded form type to remove a field from it.

```
$form = $this->createForm(new AdminEmployerForm, $employer);

// Get the embedded form...
$adminUserForm = $form->get('user');

// ... remove its email field.
$adminUserForm->remove('email');
```

Not sure of your exact use-case, but you may consider [leveraging form events](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html) as it may be more ideal than handling this in the controller.

Comment: Minor thing that I'm sure you would figure out quickly, but you have to remove the field before `$form->handleRequest($request)`.